# Validator pattern for <speak> tag

Tags: javascript, angular, regex

In angular formarray i'm using validators for input fields. For one field i'm using the regex to check the `<speak>` tag.

[image: Valid input field]

This was the valid content.

[image: Error]

Throwing error as per the pattern.

But it should throw error even if doesn't have any content inside the tags and even it have empty spaces too.
[image]

Below is the regex i've used for the validate
[image: regex]

What the changes I need to make on the regex pattern.
Thanks

Comment: so, the first example is valid `<speak>bla bla bla</speak>` you want to add attributes to tag in this case `<speak attr="test">` is also valid, the second and the third are not and is also invalid `<speak> </speak>`  becouse contains white spaces without chars. 
Is this your usecase? or i miss something

Comment: Here is my usecase scenarios:  `<speak>bla bla bla</speak>` - Valid.  `<speak attr="test">` invalid. `<speak> </speak>` - Invalid beacause of having whitespace. `<speak></speak>` - Invalid because of no text available inside.

Comment: edge cases: `<speak> bla bla bla </speak>` - starting or ending with whitespaces is Invalid? `<speak>bla bla      bla/speak>` - Valid? `<speak something>bla</speak>` - Invalid

Comment: Sorry missed those, yes you're correct

Answer (score 0):

Your regex says

`<speak` = "<speak"

`\s*` = any number of spaces (inluding 0)

`>` = ">"

`\s*` = any number of spaces (inluding 0)

`.*` = any number of characters (**including 0**)

`<\/speak>` = "</speak>"

To ensure there is at least one non-space character between tags, you can change it to:

`<speak\s*>\s*[^\s]+<\/speak>`

We replaced `.*` with `[^\s]+`

`[^\s]` means anything other than space, and `+` means **1** or more times

Update:

Because you are creating you RegExp from string, you need to escape special characters:

`Validators.pattern("<speak\\s*>\\s*[^\\s]+<\\/speak>")`

Comment: It's accepting `<speak> </speak>`. Which contains an empty space within the tag. It should have an value inside the tag

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you can try this one

```
/<speak>[^\s][^.]+[^\s]<\/speak>/gi
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to match if the content within the tags is not one or more white-space characters.

```
<speak\s*.*>\s*[^\s]+</speak>
```